# Parameter value default changes

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with different parameters for different tables.
One parameter(A) is a parameter which chooses the month for the stats we are looking at.
The other parameter(B) is for another table with dates of ending contracts.
With that parameter (B) you can choose if you want to see the ending contracts for the coming 3 months or the coming 6 months etc.

When I change parameter (A), parameter (B) 'forgets' its default value and says . This only happens when I open my report in my browser, in SSRS it works perfectly.

Can you guys help me solving this problem?